# after_update callback won't update attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Good day... I have implemented an after_update callback for a specific column that will be updated, and after that column is updated the callback is meant to add the newly updated value to another column i.e

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
after_update :update_stock, :if => :produced_changed?

private 

def update_stock
    self.stock = self.stock + self.produced 
end     
end
```

When i run rails console and run "Product.update produced:450" the stock column will automatically add the new value. i.e it works perfectly but when I try updating from the "view/controller" it doesn't work at all.

please is there a reason why?

```
2.2.4 :004 > h
 => Product id: 1, name: "MAC Air Filter", partnumber: 33440, description: "Air filter", **stock: 3440**, created_at: "2016-04-08 11:38:58", updated_at: "2016-04-19 20:33:00", **produced: 33** 

2.2.4 :006 > h.update **produced:3000**
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "produced" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products"."id" = ?  [[**"produced", 3000**], ["updated_at", "2016-04-20 13:57:59.377954"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true 

2.2.4 :007 > h
 => Product id: 1, name: "MAC Air Filter", partnumber: 33440, description: "Air filter", **stock: 6440**, created_at: "2016-04-08 11:38:58", updated_at: "2016-04-20 13:57:59", **produced: 3000**>
```

Comment: Also it is clear if you post the controller's action code also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have save the product stock to `update` the product. Here in the `update_stock` callback you only set the value of product stock. `self.stock = self.stock + self.produced` only set the value of product stock.

To update the stock value you have to save in callback as:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
after_update :update_stock, :if => :produced_changed?

private 

def update_stock
    self.stock = self.stock + self.produced
    self.save
end     
end
```

But it runs the infinite loop and gives error. So you have to set the stock value before update using before_update callback.

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_update :update_stock, :if => :produced_changed?

    private 

    def update_stock
        self.stock = self.stock + self.produced
    end     
 end
```

And **`save`** the value of product in controller.

Answer (score 1):

you should call `save` method in your callback or use callback `before_update`